# Field of mathematics which deals with similarity of a set of objects each with property variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, soft-question

(Contextual word of warning: Question written by mathematical novice.)

I have a large set of objects. Each object has three variables. Each variable is a number between 0 and 1.

For each object in the set I wish to find the n objects which are most similar based on a weight assigned to each variable.

In other words, from all the objects in set X what are the N most similar objects to object Y when we apply weights of a, b and c to variables Y1, Y2 and Y3.

I'm not after an answer, as such; I imagine there are many possible solutions.

Instead what I am after is a point in the right direction to the field of mathematics I should be reading about further, key approaches and algorithms to this problem suggested by others, keywords and phrases to be searching for.

Links, one-word answers, long-read answers, all welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if **machine learning** is a suitable field: in particular, your setup is a lot like the problem faced by **[recommender systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system)**.

That's quite a practical answer though, not so strongly mathematical. More abstractly, you might be interested in **manifold learning**? Classic algorithms in that area include CLASCAL, ISOMAP, Locally Linear Embedding, Self Organising Maps. You might not need any of those for a simple 3D setup, but maybe your data lies on an unusual manifold in the 3D space.

Comment: Does it help to know that the set of objects is static? There will not be new objects added over time. It's more of a similarity algorithm (or differing approaches to similarity algorithms) that we're after. If you think the original question would be enhanced by that fact I'll happily add it.

Comment: I don't think it needs adding to the question, no. (I didn't infer the opposite.) If you don't get the answers you want, I'd suggest saying more about what you mean by "similarity", because in your setup, one obvious answer is k-nearest-neighbours with weighted Euclidean distance - but presumably that is somehow not enough for what you want.